# Python library to automate application mouse , keyboard events for cross platform

Tags: ui-automation

Is there any library for end to end I e complete automation of applying for cross platform. I tried pyautogui,pywinauto, auoit, atomac. But none of them are completely supported.

Regards,
Ranjeet

Comment: Yes, there is no full cross-platform solution for all 3 desktop OSes. The nearest future candidates are pywinauto and Appium. pywinauto has ~50% of Linux implementation on a branch and ~10% on macOS. Appium has Windows and macOS backends, but there is no Linux support yet. I've heard that Microsoft planned to make Linux backend for Appium, but current status is not clear.

Comment: In theory there is LDTP project: cobra (Windows), LDTP (Linux) and atomac (macOS) should be API compatible but learning curve is too high.

Comment: More detailed list of competitors: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings

Comment: Hi Vasily ryabov, Thanks for the response. Pywinauto is not compatible on 64bit windows is. Appium is not freely available. Pyautogui is good, but to evaluate the return value. It always returns None. So after doing lot of research I think as of now python is not compatible still improvement is required. I have to stick to perl language.

Comment: pywinauto is compatible with 64-bit Windows. You just need to install 64-bit Python or use Application(backend=“uia”). Appium is an open source also. But not sure about learning curve. Please ask right questions and you will discover all available features.

Comment: Thanks, yes pywinauto is compatible with 64-bit, went through several links, yes pywinauto is on progress for MAC and LINUX, It will be good if its available asap.

Comment: If someone wants new features faster, some funding would be reasonable. Currently Linux is going to be released in Q2 2019. macOS should be ready later: ~Q4 2019 - Q2 2020.